# UI elements sometimes appear in the wrong place

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have the following MATLAB script:

```
fig = figure('Position', [150 30 900 600]);
%height = 2100;             % Works as expected
height = 2400;              % Elements appear in the wrong places
panel = uipanel(fig, 'Units', 'pixels', 'Position', [0 0 900 height]);
xs = linspace(-pi,pi,101);
ys = sin(xs);
width = 300;
height = 300;
yOffset = height*19;
for x = 1:3
    for y = 1:2
        a = axes(panel, 'Units', 'pixels');
        a.Position = [(x-1) * width, (y-1) * height, width, height];
        plot(a, xs, ys);
    end
end
```

When run, I expect this to create a figure containing a panel and 6 tiled axes that should fill the entire figure window. Instead, the axes elements appear to be shifted up, and partially off, of the panel and figure. This looks like:

[image: Unexpected figure]

If I change `height` to a lower number, such as `2100`, I get what I expect:

[image: Figure as expected]

Since positions are relative to the bottom left corner, I don't see why changing the height would make the axes elements move like this. It isn't a smooth transition, if the height isn't too high, the axes are in the right place, but once the height is too high, further increases in height cause the axes to move further and further up the window.

I am using MATLAB R2017a. Am I doing something wrong? What is the cause of this?

Note: I am aware that my panel is much bigger than the figure, this is intentional and desired for my application.

Comment: Is the size at which this happened related to the screen size?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I don't think so. I have tested on two different sized screens (on different computers) and it seems to act the same on both of them.